# PHP posting combination of mysqli-input and user input

Tags: php

I have a php/html table form which is populated by a combination of read-only data from a mysqli-call (the $variables in below data fields) and a user input text field at the end (input type=text). A row looks like below example:

```
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo "<strong>$navn</strong>";?></td>
    <td><?php echo "$primaereMuskelgruppe";?></td>
    <td><?php echo "$sekundaereMuskelgruppe";?></td>
    <td><?php echo "$redskab";?></td>
    <?php
    switch ($antalReps) {
        case 'Alle':?>
            <td><?php echo "$vaegt12reps";?></td>
            <td><?php echo "$vaegt10reps";?></td>
            <td><?php echo "$vaegt8reps";?></td>
            <td><?php echo "$vaegt6reps";?></td>
            <?php break;?>
        <?php case 12:?>
    <td><?php echo "$vaegt12reps";?></td>
             <?php break;?>
        <?php case 10:?>
    <td><?php echo "$vaegt10reps";?></td>
             <?php break;?> 
    <?php case 8:?>
    <td><?php echo "$vaegt8reps";?></td>
             <?php break;?> 
         <?php case 6:?>
    <td><?php echo "$vaegt6reps";?></td>
             <?php break;?>
       <?php }  ?> 
    <td><?php echo "$inkrementering";?></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="antalReps3saet"><br></td>

    <?php } ?>

</tr>
```

The table will have multiple rows.

When the user submits the table, I want to post the data from each row on a separate page (for use in a different function), and iterate through each row separately, both accessing the mysqli-data and the user input data.

I'm pretty sure I need to make and post arrays, but I can't figure out how to include both read-only and user input.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly... This code is creating a form which will post to another page, and all of these values need to be included in that post?

In that case, all of these values need to be form values.  DOM structure isn't included in a POST request, form element values are.  For example, you have one form element here:

```
<input type="text" name="antalReps3saet">
```

This, however, is not a form element:

```
<td><?php echo "$vaegt6reps";?></td>
```

So the value of `$vaegt6reps` would need to be in a form element.  You could use the elements directly in-line with your code and rely on styling to make them look like non-form (display only) DOM elements:

```
<td><input type="text" name="vaegt6reps" value="<?php echo "$vaegt6reps";?>"></td>
```

The styling could get tricky, and the UX could get weird depending on the browser if users discover that these are form elements.  (You'd want to disable them to make them "read-only" as you say, though keep in mind that any user can manipulate values in any form POST if they want to.  "Read-only" is a false sense of security in this case.)

So instead of that you might put the values alongside their displays as hidden form elements:

```
<td><?php echo "$vaegt6reps";?><input type="hidden" name="vaegt6reps" value="<?php echo "$vaegt6reps";?>"></td>
```

A savvy user can still modify the value before performing the POST, there's really nothing you can do about that other than to not rely on client-side values.  But the UX would be easier to maintain in this case.

Comment: Thanks @David - that's just the ticket :) And also thanks for your detailed explanation - it's much appreciated!